# Some good derogatory terms for nobility or upper class?

Tags: terminology, pejorative-language

I'm in need of some derogatory terms for nobles for a story I'm writing, something for a fantastical medieval based world. The more the merrier!

Comment: List-type questions are off topic here. Please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: How about "The 1%"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Which premise is false?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast For one thing, *upper class* and *nobility* are orthagonal, though historically correlated. One relates to economics and the other to genetics, and terms may not be applicable: Bill Gates isn't a *toff*, Prince Charles isn't a *plutocrat*, Martha Custis wasn't a *yuppie*, etc.

Comment: @choster - Read the post. This refers to "a fantastical medieval based world". The great thing about fantasy is that the writer gets to make the rules. How do you know that within the story the two classes are not identical? Furthermore, your objection to the misuse of proposed terms is to criticize (and suppress) the question because you don't like the suggested answers. Doesn't seem fair. (Although I agree with rejecting Yuppie in this context).

Answer (score 1):

> Yuppies.

Especially if they are riding in an open-top carriage.

Comment: A noble can't be a yuppy by definition.

Answer (score 1):

A [Toff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toff).

> a derogatory stereotype for someone with an aristocratic background or belonging to the landed gentry, particularly someone who exudes an air of superiority.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified why the derogatory term(s) would be applicable.

Is it because the nobility is a pampered, ineffectual class which gives itself airs?

**inbred twit**, **mincing fops**, **jaded halfwits**, **privileged ninnies**, **pampered parasites**

On the other hand, are they competent rulers who run roughshod over their subjects?

**callous oppressors**, **bloody-handed bastards**, **sadistic scum**, **privileged tyrants**, **sanctimonious despots**

Answer (score 0):

**Eurotrash** derogatory term applicable to rich, decadent Europeans living in New York, Los Angeles and San Francisco. Popular term for these people in the 1980s. See Wikipedia for more on ' Eurotrash' etymology. See also 'International White trash'.